# issues updating cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, installation

I am having a problem updating Cocos2d to the current version. I deleted the old template files and installed the new version using the command

```
./install-templates.sh -u -f
```

but I always get the following in the terminal:

```
Installing Xcode 4 Box2d iOS template
-------------------------------------------------

mkdir: /Users/jubilate/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos2d v2.x: Permission denied
...copying Box2d files
rsync: mkdir "/Users/jubilate/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos2d v2.x/lib_box2d.xctemplate/libs" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(544) [receiver=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(452) [sender=2.6.9]
rsync: mkdir "/Users/jubilate/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos2d v2.x/lib_box2d.xctemplate/libs" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(544) [receiver=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(452) [sender=2.6.9]
done!

Installing Xcode 4 CCNode file templates...
----------------------------------------------------

...creating destination directory: /Users/jubilate/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File   Templates/cocos2d v2.x/
mkdir: /Users/jubilate/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/cocos2d v2.x: Permission denied
mv: rename /Users/jubilate/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos2d v2.x//CCNode   class.xctemplate to /Users/jubilate/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/cocos2d v2.x/:   No such file or directory
done!
```

Could someone please help me out. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue as well. It turned out to due to my previous cocos2d (v1) was installed as "root".

If you do a

```
ls -ltr /Users/jubilate/Library/Developer/Xcode/
```

you will see that permission of "Templates" is "root staff"

you need to "sudo -s", enter your root user password, then

```
cd "/Users/jubilate/Library/Developer/Xcode/"
chown jubilate:staff Templates
```

this will change the permission of "Templates" to "jubilate staff", which you can then do the installation.

Give it a go and see how it goes.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed the previous templates with the sudo command. You will have to manually delete the files in Finder.

Delete these folders beginning with "cocos2d":

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos2d*
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/cocos2d*
```

Comment: i have deleted them but I still have the same issue